# distinct merging select results in mssql keeping order of each results

Tags: sql-server

my website is a sort of dictionary. when a keyword is searched I want to look in to both 'word' and 'meaning' column and display all that matches either word or meaning.

```
select count(id) words where word like @keyword or meaning like @keyword 
select * from words where word like @keyword or meaning like @keyword order by word
```

but I want to first show the matching words and then the matching meanings. the order is not correct

when I separate them:

```
select count(id) words where word like @keyword
select * from words where word like @keyword order by word
select count(id) words where meaning like @keyword 
select * from words where meaning like @keyword  order by word
```

this way there are duplicates (when keyword matches both word and meaning)

and when I union them again the order won't be correct

how can this be done? I need the count of distinct matching results + the distinct matching results itself but first showing matching words and then the matching meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case statement in your ORDER BY clause to distinguish when it's a match on the word:

```
select  * 
from    words 
where   word like @keyword or meaning like @keyword 
order by 
        case when word like @keyword then 0 else 1 end
        , word
```